# Rails redirecting to a 'show' path when given another path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, link-to

I have a custom route called "work_path" and when I try to access it I get this error

```
"Missing template portfolios/show"
```

I am **not** trying to access the "show" view, but rather one named "work" (work.html.erb).  I have no idea why it keeps trying to get me to the "show view"

My custom route

```
get 'portfolios/work' =>  'portfolios#work', :as => :work
```

Portolios Controller

```
def work
@portfolio = @portfolio.active
end
```

The link I'm using:

```
<%= link_to "Work", work_path %>
```

I don't know why it's trying to redirect me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have also `resources :portfolios` in routes.rb above your custom route and that causes your problem. Switch these lines' positions.